# Redirect routes angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, redirect, router

I have an error in my Route  I don't know why it doesn't work especially for this page.
So, I have an application web, I add a template to my application : two components(template-un and template-deux).
after that I added their selector in appcomponent like that :

```
<div class="page">
    <app-template-un></app-template-un>
    <app-template-deux></app-template-deux> 
</div>
```

So, now I'd like to add authentication page, I create a new component write the necessary code html and typescript.
After that I changed appcomponent to :

```
<app-login></app-login>
```

When I run my application I get the login page, the problem is here, when I enter the login and password  and validate. when I validate it redirect me to dashboard page in the url but it still the same page of login 
here my login component:

```
onSubmit() { 
            console.log(`username: ${this.username} password: ${this.password}`)

           if(this.username == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin'){
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
           }
          }
```

Any ideas to help me please

Comment: you code is going into `if` statement, have you debugged it?

Comment: yes, and  I have no problems

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

It should be `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])`.

Or you can use `this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard')`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']).
```

Comment: I try it but doesn't work, it redirect me in the url  to http://localhost:4200/dashboard but the content doesn't change

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router){}

onSubmit() { 
            console.log(`username: ${this.username} password: 
            ${this.password}`)

           if(this.username == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin'){

             this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in your `app.component.html` file.

Comment: move it to app.component.html from there

Comment: I try it, and I have two page in one, it's not the issue